# Two holomorphic functions with same absolute value on boundary of disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck on an exercise, which goes as follows:

$ r\in\mathbb{R}_{>0} $. Let $ f,g:\overline{U_r(0)}\rightarrow\mathbb{C} $ be continuous and without zero. Let $ f,g $ be holomorphic on $ U_r(0) $ and $ |f(z)|=|g(z)| $ for all $ z\in\partial U_r(0) $. Show that there is a $ \lambda\in\mathbb{C} $ with $ |\lambda|=1 $, such that $ f=\lambda g $.

I tried solving this with Cauchy's Integral Formula, but this would assume that $ f,g $ are holomorphic on $ \partial U_r(0) $, which obviously isn't given. Can someone give a hint on how to solve this?

Comment: apply maximum modulus to $f/g, g/f$

Comment: Thank you! I now know that $|f(z)|=|g(z)|$ for all $ z\in U_r(0) $. But couldn't $ \lambda $ be different for every $ z $? How do I show that there is one $ \lambda $ for all $ z $?

Comment: maximum modulus shows that $f/g$ is constant not only that $|f/g|$ is constant